# Drawble is not changing though selector while providing custom state?

Tags: android

Main XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.zzz.example.app.custom.selector.BankErrorSelectorView
        android:id="@+id/bank_parent_error_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_8"
        app:state_fluctuate="false"
        android:background="@drawable/bank_error_border_layout_selector"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_8">
```

Class

```
class BankErrorSelectorView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    private var isStateFluctuate = false

    override fun onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace: Int): IntArray {
        if (isStateFluctuate) {
            val drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1)
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_FLUCTUATE)
            return drawableState
        } else {
            return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace)
        }
    }

    fun setBankErrorState(state: Boolean) {
        isStateFluctuate = state
        refreshDrawableState()
    }

    companion object {
        private val STATE_FLUCTUATE = intArrayOf(R.attr.state_fluctuate)
    }
}
```

ATTR:

```
<declare-styleable name="BankErrorSelectorView">
        <attr name="state_fluctuate" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <item
            app:state_fluctuate="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/border_rectangle_red" />
    
        <item
            app:state_fluctuate="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/border_rectangle_yellow" />
    
    </selector>
```

Whn I'm passing true from either XML or even directly from the BankErrorSelectorView-setBankErrorState class still in UI no changes!

What I'm doing wrong? I saw many example on stackoverflow1